# C# Path Compression Issue

Tags: string, c#-4.0, registry

I'm having an issue with path compression. I'm reading a registry value, such as %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming. The problem I'm having is it keeps expanding the the path out to C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming. 
I know about Environment Expand, but I don't want to use that in case I have an path compression issue in the future. The code I'm using is:

```
RegistryKey hkUsersPath = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(@".DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\");

DefaultAppData = Convert.ToString(hkUsersPath.GetValue("AppData"));
if (hkUsersPath.GetValue("AppData") == null)
DefaultAppData = Convert.ToString(hkUsersPath.GetValue("APPDATA"));
```

Any advice is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's an [overloaded GetValue method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzxd58z1.aspx) that you can call where you can specify not to expand environment variables:

```
hkUsersPath.GetValue("AppData", null, RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I was looking through the overloaded methods, but I guess I overlooked it. Works perfectly!